# Why won't my Nokia E52 charge on some USB ports

Tags: usb, charging, nokia-e-series

I have two computers. If I connect my Nokia to one of them using the usb cable the charge process will start. If I connect the phone to the other computer (using the same cable!) it won't start charging.

Any suggestions what the problem is?

(I couldn't find a usb related difference between both computers)

Answer (score 2):

Some USB ports are able to provide power as well as data transfer, others can be data only. Sometimes some USB ports on one computer will be one way, while other ports on the same computer will be the other way.

Comment: Might some USB ports provide less power then others, too? (I think so, but I don't know the facts.)

Comment: None of the usb ports of the "problem" computer does work. My MP3 player charges happily on the same ports.

Comment: You're able to charge your MP3 player on the problem pc, but not the Nokia? Perhaps the devices have different power requirements...that's all I've got.

Comment: -1 All standard-compliant USB ports must provide power for devices! Device may consume 1 unit load (100mA for USB2.0 and older, 150mA for USB 3.0) without negotiating power consumption. Computer may refuse to provide more than 1 unit load to device. There are USB ports with power-only. They have a resistor between D+ and D- lines, so device know that port won't talk back. Please provide good source on "data only" USB ports if you want to get rig of my down-vote.

Comment: Speaking anecdotally (sp?) I've had USB ports on previous computers that did not provide power. In addition, I've used USB hubs that did not provide power.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: would be -1 if there were negative rating on comments. Yes, USB2.0 ports should and can always provide 100mA (do laptops with USB3 ever exist?), but that is *just not enough*. Typical charging requirement of cellphone is 400-500mA (while USB player has much smaller battery and lesser charge current), and I once seen a PDA (Eten Glofiish X500+) which wouldn't charge at *any* usb port because it sunk almost 1A, and so worked only with original supply. (For the latter case, I checked the ID pin in connector: it was connected to ground.)

Comment: @whitequark My point were "data only" USB ports. Your comment is correct in sense that not all devices can be charged/powered over USB and that some devices may need to negotiate additional current, but just as you said all USB ports need to provide 100mA. The 100mA conflicts with "data only" statement. If OP said what you did:  "USB2.0 ports should and can always provide 100mA (do laptops with USB3 ever exist?), but that is just not enough." that would have been correct and I wouldn't have complained at all.

Comment: @Grant Palin Can you please name a computer (laptop model or motherboard model) where a non-damaged, correctly connected USB port did not provide any power at all? As in you connect a flash drive and it's dead until you connect powered hub in-between drive and port? If you only have anecdotal evidence, then "I've heard that ..." or something similar should be used IMHO. Also, sorry for answering after so long. I didn't see your reply. Using @username displays little blue envelope and shows comments in "summary" tab.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Quite a necro-thread, but I just wanted to input that on my work computer Lenovo T410, the left hand side USB port below the Display Port port (eh..) will not charge the Nokia E52, but the USB port next to it (bottom row) charges it just fine. This happens even without choosing "PC Suite" or any other connectivity mode.

Comment: @Juha Untinen After experimenting with USB ports on laptops (which often provide voltages on the bottom part of acceptable range) and thin cables often used for USB A to micro USB B cables (and I guess many small proprietary connectors), the only only thing that comes to my mind that could explain the behavior is that for some reason, there is a small difference in output voltages between USB ports under load.

Comment: @Juha Untinen Combined with high resistance of the cable (which can be surprisingly high! I've had cases of as much as 0.7 V drop on a USB cable), it could result in a voltage that is too low for the phone to start charging.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here: My Nokia won't charge, if I connect it to the USB-hub built into my Dell monitor, but my MP3 will.

And Grant Palin is right: It's a power requirement issue. If I connect my Nokia directly to a USB-port on the computer, it charges as it should.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced that on some laptops:

The phone won't charge while the laptop is only running on battery – but when the power adapter is connected to the laptop, the phone is charging.

Answer (score 1):

I'm here of course because I've experienced the same issue.  I changed computers at work and when I plugged my e-52 into the new PC, *no charge*.

Let's recap some basics:

- When you plug your e-52 into a computer for the first time, a pop-up window appears "New Hardware Found. Do You Want to Download Software?"  Here I clicked *YES*. For some unknown reason, my PC couldn't locate the software.  Let's not get into why.  I think here you need to manually download PC Suite or OVI Suite.  I didn't want to at this stage.
- Another thing is, when you plug e-52 into the PC, the phone gives you a list of MODES that you have to choose one from to continue:

  - PC Suite
  - Mass Storage
  - Image Transfer
  - Connect to Web
- When I chose *PC Suite*, my phone wouldn't charge.  When I chose Mass Storage, Eureka, it did!

My conclusion is, when you choose the PC Suite mode, the e-52 needs to communicate with the respective software on your PC before in kicks into the charge mode.  If your PC doesn't have the appropriate software, the phone won't charge (at least for the first time you plug in your phone).

If that's the problem your having, **simply disconnect your phone and plug it back in choosing Mass Storage** instead of PC Suite mode.  From this point on, every time you plug your e-52 in, it should automatically begin charging.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with my Nokia E52.
When I plug the phone into a generic USB charger via a micro-USB cable, the phone does not charge. However my bluetooth headset happily charges via the same charger and cable.
Also, the phone is only being charged when the laptop is plugged into the power cord, not in battery mode or standby mode, whereas the headset is being charged whenever it is connected to the laptop.

Apparently the phone requires more power than some other devices.

Comment: Charging a battery requires much more power than simply operating a keyboard or a mouse, it's normal.